# Vim - Is there a way to get immediate visual feedback during Insert in Visual Block Mode?

Tags: vim, vi

I often press:

- `<Ctrl> V` to go into visual block mode and highlight a column
- hit `<shift>-i` (to insert at the beginning of the line), type a few things (at this point, I see my changes on the first line, but not any others).
- and then hit `<Esc>` to go back to normal mode.

After I hit `<Esc>`, I see the stuff I inserted get put in each of the other lines.

What I would like is to visually see my changes on each line, as I type, rather than only on the first line. Is that possible?

**Go into Visual Block, select a bunch of lines**
[image]

**Hit `<Shift> i`**
[image]

**Add some text** - This is the part I'd like to be changed. I'd like for the spaces to be immediately visible on all lines, not just the first line.
[image]

**Hit Escape** - Now the spaces are added on every line. I'd like for this to happen sooner. 
[image]

**I know that I could have done what I did in this example with `>>`.** I chose a simplified example to illustrate the thing I'd like to change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your [vimrc](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vimrc):

```
nmap <buffer> <silent> <expr> <F12> InsertCol()
imap <buffer> <silent> <expr> <F12> InsertCol()

function! InsertCol()
    let w:first_call = exists('w:first_call') ? 0 : 1
    "if w:first_call
    "    startinsert
    "endif
    try
        let char = getchar()
    catch /^Vim:Interrupt$/
        let char = "\<Esc>"
    endtry
    if char == '^\d\+$' || type(char) == 0
        let char = nr2char(char)
    endif " It is the ascii code.
    if char == "\<Esc>"
        unlet w:first_call
        return char
    endif
    redraw
    if w:first_call
        return char."\<Esc>gvA\<C-R>=Redraw()\<CR>\<F12>"
    else
        return char."\<Esc>gvlA\<C-R>=Redraw()\<CR>\<F12>"
    endif
endfunction

function! Redraw()
    redraw
    return ''
endfunction
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> as usual, and then press <kbd>F12</kbd>.  It will insert and show all lines changed for each keystroke.

Note: The script would be better if pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> would go into insert mode, instead of requiring you to press <kbd>I</kbd> each time.  Maybe the `startinsert` command in combination with `vnoremap` could do this.

Comment: Sweet! `vmap I I<F12>` along with your script does the job.  Do you know if there's a way to make the cursor appear on the line while the insert's happening?

Comment: This page appears to offer a solution to the cursor problem: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Wait_for_user_input_(getchar)_without_moving_cursor

Comment: Yes, it works -- add this to make the cursor appear on the line: `imap <F12>ignore-me <Nop>`

Comment: That doesn't work for me.